# How to do a non-linear perspective stretch with OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, perspective, stretch

I need to perform a kind of image stretching that will scale less at the top and more at the bottom. I don't what to lose parts of the image like warpPerspective. Is this kind of function available with OpenCV?

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wolGn.png)

[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWV9l.png)

Answer (score 2):

I found a way using [remap](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=remap#remap) function and remapping each pixel by using an exponential function:

```
   cv::Mat mapX, mapY;
   mapX.create(m_nRemapHeight, m_nRemapWidth, CV_32FC1);
   mapY.create(m_nRemapHeight, m_nRemapWidth, CV_32FC1);

   for (int j = 0; j < m_nRemapHeight; j++)
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < m_nRemapWidth; i++)
      {
         mapX.at<float>(j, i) = (float)i;
         float t = (m_nRemapHeight * 0.5f);    
         float r = j + t;
         float fVal = ((r*r) / (m_nRemapHeight + t * 2));
         fVal -= ((t*t) / (m_nRemapHeight + t * 2));
         mapY.at<float>(j, i) = fVal;
      }
   }
   cv::remap(srcMat, dstMat, matX, matY, CV_INTER_LINEAR, 0);
```